# Command is not found when ran with sudo

Tags: node.js, permissions, sudo, n

I am trying to change the version of *nodejs* using cmd `n` installed globally by `yarn`. Neither `yarn` is detected by `sudo` nor `n`.

Please help me to fix this:

When running the `n` command to change node version, it shows ***permission is denied by many files*** to be written by `n`

[image]

Comment: It's not in PATH for sudo, so just specify the full path `sudo /home/ec2-user/.yarn/bin/n 14.17.2`

Comment: I was not knowing this concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to avoid permission issues without requiring use of sudo when running `n`:

- install and run Node.js from your home folder using `N_PREFIX` and `PATH` (see also `n-install` which automates this)
- if it is your personal computer, take ownership of the folders used with default install location of `/usr/local`

See the project README for more: https://github.com/tj/n

(Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of `n`.)